# How to detach a spawned child process in a Node.js script?

Tags: node.js

Intent: call an external application with specified arguments, and exit script.

The following script does not work as it should:

```
 #!/usr/bin/node
 var cp = require('child_process');
 var MANFILE='ALengthyNodeManual.pdf';
 cp.spawn('gnome-open', ['\''+MANFILE+'\''], {detached: true});
```

Things tried: `exec` - does not detach. Many thanks in advance

Comment: tangentially: [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) defaults to not run your command in a shell, so you don't need to put single quotes around the `MANFILE` argument.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From node.js documentation:

> By default, the parent will wait for the detached child to exit. To prevent the parent from waiting for a given child, use the child.unref() method, and the parent's event loop will not include the child in its reference count.
>
> When using the detached option to start a long-running process, the process will not stay running in the background unless it is provided with a stdio configuration that is not connected to the parent. If the parent's stdio is inherited, the child will remain attached to the controlling terminal.

You need to modify your code something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
var fs = require('fs');
var out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');
var err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

var cp = require('child_process');
var MANFILE='ALengthyNodeManual.pdf';
var child = cp.spawn('gnome-open', [MANFILE], { detached: true, stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ] });
child.unref();
```

Comment: You can set "ignore" for stdin, stdout, stderr:

`stdio: ['ignore' /* stdin */, 'ignore' /* stdout */, 'ignore' /* stderr */]`

Comment: The most important part to ensure the decoupling of the child process from the parent process is the last line `child.unref();`
Also `stdio: 'ignore'` can be used to silence all (stdin/stdout/stderr)

Comment: This is good for bouncing a server remotely:
Server spawns a detatched clone of itself and exits.

Comment: Hey - I copy-pasted this with the right amends, and it does not work as expected. I have a service running on a docker container, through an API it launches a shell script responsible to update the image. Although the moment the docker instance is destroyed, the spawn dies too. Suggestions?

Comment: Isn't `child.disconnect();` required before `child.unref();`? I'm on Linux and without it the parent process doesn't exit until the child exited.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem:

app.js

```
require('./spawn.js')('node worker.js');
```

spawn.js

```
module.exports = function( command ) {
    require('child_process').fork('./spawner.js', [command]); 
};
```

spawner.js

```
require('child_process').exec(
    'start cmd.exe @cmd /k "' + process.argv[2] + '"', 
    function(){}
);
process.abort(0);
```

Comment: I'm adding this here even though you have selected an answer, because my google searches left me with no obvious alternate solutions.

Comment: This is, as you can see, OS-specific. Not very helpful for those on OS X and Unix/Linux. The accepted answer uses the node.js own standard libraries.

Comment: The intent was to: _create a detached command terminal and pass a command_ aka start a process. 'child_process' sadly falls slightly short of the need to spawn independent processes from the master in this respect. Just replace with your Linux flavor: xterm, xdg-open. Unless you can show me way to do that with your code... that works on both windows and linux then. ;P Like I said I'm trying to solve a problem that is close but not quite near to where you want to be. Google threw me here, as my last hope before I gave up and figured something out for myself. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I just found out that fork() of a Web application will will try to use the same IP address & port already being used by the parent.  So the child will error `EADDRINUSE`