# Node.js why does a child process not start right away?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I'm trying to write a global node command line program that will take any (windows or unix) console command I give to it and execute it in a new console window. I also want the program to exit after it has spawned its process so the console I'm using isn't blocked by a node script that has a child process running.

This is a simple version of what I have so far:

myScript.js:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("start startScript.cmd"); // windows start command opens a new cmd window
process.exit(0);
```

startScript.cmd:

```
mkdir test
```

I have also tried this (But this doesn't work even without the process.exit):

myScript.js:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('start', ['startScript.cmd'], { detached: true, stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore']});
child.unref();
process.exit(0);
```

The problem is, calling process.exit() seems to prevent the child process from fully starting and so nothing happens unless I do some setTimeout shenanigans. However the behavior seems random. On a different computer it behaves like I want it to. Both computers have the same version of node (v0.10.33).

The directory test is never made unless I remove the process.exit line or use a setTimeout on it.

Any idea why this happens or how to get around it? Keep in mind I don't want to wait until the child process is finished. I want to be able to return to my command line immediately.

Thanks!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871740/how-to-detach-spawned-child-process-in-a-node-js-script.  `.spawn()` and `child.unref()` and separate stdio streams.

Comment: I have actually tried that. Also if that was the issue, any time I try to call process.exit() while the child is still running would cause the child to close too. But this is not my case, as even a process that runs for like 10 seconds will stay up if I use a setTimeout of 0 ms over the exit call. Also spawn wont let me use the start command.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question then?  If it does what you want with a short `setTimeout()` before exiting, then why don't you just use that?

Comment: Because it's gross and I'm hoping to make multiple child processes run different commands. I suppose I could just get the number of commands I'm going to run and like multiply that by some number of ms and have that be my setTimeout amount. But yeah.... It seems like the act of opening up a new window takes too long so it never fully starts even though as far as exec is concerned, it ran the command.

Comment: So, then change your question to "why is a `setTimeout()` needed to reliably start a stand-alone child process if that' what you really want to know.

Comment: Using the windows start command in the node script is not working well. If I move it out to another script that is responsible for the start, then things seem to work a lot better. Also spawn just really hates start for some reason, but is now working with just a reference to another script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The answer is: don't use exec and don't use start or call or any other weird windows command in the spawn call. Set the CWD if need be in the spawn options and either spawn what you want directly or make a OS specific script that calls your command if it still isn't working. One example of a windows script is literally just:

```
%*
```

That way, start or any other weird windows command will be executed correctly (but do you really need them?).