# Send nodejs script to background in php without blocking

Tags: php, node.js, bash

I have a nodejs script which opens a torrent stream which I then use to grab screenshots from. Currently I use a bash script for this which is not really extensible. I decided to move most of this to php by using a handy `FFMpeg` wrapper for php.

The problem is that I can't seem to initiate the nodejs script from within php without blocking. This is the command I'm running using `exec()`

```
node ~/node/peerflix/app.js 'test.torrent' &> /dev/null &
```

However whatever I try, the script hangs on exec. I just want to send it to the background. In other words, how can I asynchronously execute a nodejs script and send it to the background without caring about the output.

**It would also be nice to be able to get the PID of the process so I can kill it when I'm done**

*I've been doing some research on ReactPHP and perhaps that would be a solution but I have no idea how to get that going.*

Comment: Why not using 'forever'?

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871740/how-to-detach-spawned-child-process-in-a-node-js-script). Also how about using a [screen](http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html)?

Comment: @BenDiamant what is 'forever'?

Comment: @laggingreflex I looked at the screen option but that's the same dirty fix as putting that line that I posted in a bash file and simply running that. Trying to clean up code and keep it somewhat maintainable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest something:

Use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) for manageable  running.

You can use it in a javascript runner script of as a bash (my favor)

```
npm install forever -g

forever start  ~/node/peerflix/app.js 'test.torrent' //in bash
```

This will run app.js forever, and can be monitored with the forever cli

Comment: But I don't want the script to run continuously. I want to kill the script immediately when the PHP is done processing.

Comment: You can do it with forever start, forever stop