# Small Continous Integration Script - Deploy Methods

Tags: node.js, architecture, continuous-integration, devops

I'm working on a small projects between some collaborators, and I'm about to setup a continous integration workflow. I'm looking into Bamboo or Jenkins, but for now, since we are still in the early stages and quite small, I'm building the workflow myself in NodeJS.

A design question: I have a server running constantly that listens to my repository and pulls updates when they occur. This server then deploys the application by starting its node application script (currently it happens locally).

Now, I want to spawn the application process *independently* of my deployment script. But I also want to make sure that it keeps running.

[image]

My question is, what is the industry way of going about this? And what is recommendable given the very small size (= 2 collaborators) on the project so far?

I have been thinking that this could be achieved by:

- Executing shell scripts from the listening script process that spawns the application process
- Running node commands from the listening shell process that spawns the application process

However, I don't see how I can liberate the application from the listening script, and I assume I should, since my application crashes if the listening script goes down which is undesired.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you cannot spawn a process without it actually being a child. But maybe if you use `detached` with the right stdio setup as in this question: [How to detach a spawned child process in a Node.js script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871740/how-to-detach-a-spawned-child-process-in-a-node-js-script)

To make sure Node programs keep running, people use things like PM2 or supervisor.  I'm sure that making a CI program is an interesting exercise but as far as counting on it for everyday use, I would not try to make my own..just use CircleCI, Strider, or Travis.

Bamboo and Jenkins are well established but not especially popular with the Node crowd, possibly because they are built with Java.