# Node.js - Execute standalone process that does not shutdown when parent process stops/restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I need to start a standalone process (separate app) from within my node.js application, without it acting as a child process.

I'm not able to keep a process alive that has been launched with process.spawn, even though the detached: true is set. The spawned process should be completely standalone and not get killed when the Node.js app restarts or crashes.

This is what I have so far:

```
let cp = spawn('./background_script', args, {
    detached: true,
    stdio: [ 'ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore' ]
});
cp.unref();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be right: [How to detach a spawned child process in a Node.js script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871740/how-to-detach-a-spawned-child-process-in-a-node-js-script).  Which platform are you running it on?

Comment: I've looked at various SO posts, including the one you mentioned. Still not able to make it work. The spawned process runs fine up until the nodejs process restarts or is stopped.