# Reload all pm2 clusters from within 1 of the clusters

Tags: node.js, pm2, spawn

I have a nodejs application running on multiple pm2 clusters. I created a route through which I update the code for the application (pull new code from Git remote) and then I attempt to reload all pm2 clusters by using `exec` to run reload command (pm2 reload [server]).

The problem I encountered is, once the cluster that that initiated the process terminates in order to reload, it won't continue reloading the remaining clusters.

So, after researching (Reading [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_unref) and looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871740/how-to-detach-a-spawned-child-process-in-a-node-js-script)) it seemed obvious that the correct way to handle this, is to `spawn` a child process and run the `unref()` method on it. This, however, didn't change anything. Some clusters reload but not all.

Here's the code:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const reload = spawn(`pm2`, [`reload`, `server`], {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
reload.unref();
```

I also tried adding `reload.disconnect()`, based on the node 
, but got an error `disconnect is not a function`.

In addition, instead of running the command 'pm2 reload server' in the child process, I tried executing a bash file, that contained the command, through the detached child process. The results were the same.

In summary I want to know how to have the reloads for all clusters continue even after the cluster that initiated the process terminates.
I would also like to know, why the ways I have tried did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why it wasn't working the way I posted in the question.

However, what did work for me is running a js file with the detached spawned child process, that in turn runs a detached spawned child process that executes the reload command.

In the first file I have:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const reload = spawn(`node`, [`/reload.js`], {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
reload.unref();
```

and in reload.js I have:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const reload = spawn(`pm2`, [`reload`, `server`], {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
reload.unref();
```

Note: I first tried using `exec` in reload.js and that got the same results outlined in the question.

I hope this helps anyone trying to accomplish anything similar.