# How do i send commands from nodejs to a powershell terminal?

Tags: node.js, powershell

I have 2 tools that I want to talk to each other or at least one tool should be able to send commands to the other. Both of the tools run from the terminal (PowerShell) but one is in NodeJS and the other is written in python. I don't have the ability to change anything on the python tool so I was wondering if its possible to connect somehow to the python tool through the NodeJS tool. I looked into com serial ports and stuff like that but I'm very new to that stuff. There's also the option of nodes child_process but a requirement that I need is once the python tool is started I don't want it closed when the NodeJS tool is closed (this would close some processes that take a long time to start up). Any advice would be much appreciated. :)

Edit:
The python tool runs in PowerShell and it needs to be always on. Now I want to use that tool through the NodeJS tool. So I need to attach the NodeJS tool somehow to the python tool. It can be through another PowerShell child instance but I never wanna close the python tool and the NodeJS tool should and will be open and closed randomly. Its also ok to start the python tool first time with the NodeJS tool.

Comment: You can detach the child process from node https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871740/how-to-detach-a-spawned-child-process-in-a-node-js-script

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes but i need to connect to it after the nodejs tool is closed and opened again

Comment: Please update your question with more details about the input and output you want to exchange between these processes. What exactly are your expectations when you say you want to "connect" to a running process? Should you be able to react to `input()` prompts from the program? Or do you just want to see the output?

Comment: I want to be able to use the second tool (python tool) like it was spawned with child_process even if the nodejs tool closes and reopens. If its easier its also sufficient to just send strings to the stdio of the second terminal (python tool). For example i need to run a command that would be like "tool do_something" but i want to do it programmatically from the nodejs tool